# Python argparse, passing multiple arguments into the command line.

Tags: python, argparse

I am writing a python script.

It takes two arguments, a file, and the optional argument of a set of rules. The rules need to be formatted as a dictionary.

I am new to `argparse` and want to make this command line friendly.

If I leave the optional argument out and just type in the file, the script runs perfectly. If I add in a test dictionairy, it returns --

```
har_parser.py: error: unrecognized arguments:
```

I am not sure if it my misuse of the command line, which would be an easy fix if I need to change how I am passing in arguments.

Currently I am running the script as so...:

```
$ python myScript.py arg1 arg2
```

The other more likely scenario is that I wrote my function incorrectly, due to my novice experience with argparse.

Any direction would be appreciated.

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("file", nargs=1)
    parser.add_argument("--rules")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.rules:
        print(parseHar(str(args.file[0]), args.rules[0]))
    else:
        print(parseHar(str(args.file[0])))
```

Comment: What is the exact command you entered into command line that has given you the error?

Comment: Your parser expects something like: `myScript.py arg1 --rules arg2` or `myScipt.py --rules arg1 arg2`.  The result will be a `Namespace` with `args.file` and `args.rules` attributes.  WIth `nargs=1`, `args.file`will be a 1 element list.  Without it, will be a simple string.  Try various inputs and print `args`.